# How can I use my laptop as a Bluetooth input device?

Tags: networking, usb, bluetooth, android, gamepad

I just got a USB bluetooth dongle, and I'd like to use it to

1. Connect my laptop to my Android tablet as a slave device.

   and
2. Route input from my USB Xbox 360 controller to the bluetooth dongle.

I want to do this so I can play games on my tablet with my controller, while the tablet's micro USB port is occupied by a charging cable. And just because it would be awesome.

Does Ubuntu have any tools that would make this easier? I can currently pair with the tablet, but only as a master- the options in Blueman manager are "Audio Source" and "Network Access Point"; I want to be able to see my laptop as a slave (an "input device" or "game controller" or something) from my Android device's bluetooth menu. Is this even possible?

Comment: Really good question.  In theory it should be, but I don't know if there is any software to do it.